# How to extract .tar.bz2?

Tags: tar

I'm downloading an engine game file which is compressed as .tar.bz2.

I'm trying this command

```
tar -zxvf enginsxt.tar.bz2
```

And it throws an error. I know that command

```
tar -zxvf
```

is only for extracting `.tar.gz` files, but how can I decompress this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: `tar xf enginsxt.tar.bz2` works well enough with anything tar-related, you don't really need to specify the compression used anymore; welcome to the 21st century!

Comment: I tried [this](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/untar-file-linuxubuntu/) and it worked.

Answer (score 86):

Have you checked the `man` page for `tar`?

Here is the part that I extracted from `man` page of `tar` for `bz2`:

```
-j, --bzip2
          filter the archive through bzip2
```

Remove `-z` from your options and (optionally) add `-j` to extract your tar archive correctly:

```
tar -xvjf enginsxt.tar.bz2
```

Comment: It still needs the `f` as the last option letter before the **f**ilename I think: either `xvjf ` or plain `xvf` (or even `xf` if you don't care about verbosity) since `tar` is smart enough to figure out the compression type... except when wrong-footed with an erroneous type, as the OP did.

Comment: that is right, kinda missed that, but he can figure that out from man page:-)

Comment: Out of all letters, how did they arrive to `j`?